# Converting date formats after executing stored procedure via Powershell?

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell

I have sort of a weird issue here. We have several stored procedures in MS SQL Server. When we execute the procedures via Management Studio, we are seeing this specific column being output as just a date. When we execute the stored procedure via Powershell and stuff the contents into a text file, the value is shown as a DateTime. We want to remove the time from this column so it just displays the date.

Why is the column's value shown as a DateTime when executing via Powershell, but not when running the procedure via Management Studio and how can I convert that value via Powershell?

EDIT:

This is the code I'm using:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "xxx" -Database "xxx" -Query "xxx" -Username "xxx" -Password "xxx" -QueryTimeout 600 | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -delimiter "`t" -Path $myFilePath
gc $myFilePath | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | out-file $myCompanyFile -Fo -En ascii
```

EDIT2:

In SQL Server, we converted the date fields to strings and that worked for us.

Comment: The format of a date is completely controlled by the presentation layer. it seems here you aren't defining a format, so you get the default format for what you're using. Powershell uses .Net datatypes, which only has a `DateTime` datatype (there's isn't a `date`), therefore your `date` column will be treated by Powershell as a `DateTime` and hence why it also displayed a time portion.

Comment: Total guess, but you could likely use the `ToString` function and the format `yyyyMMdd` to solve this. Guess, because we have no PowerShell Scripts from you to show what you're doing.

Comment: Exactly - I was going to add as a reminder that nobody can see your screen. You have to provide sufficient information in the question.

Comment: This is interesting. I'm using PowerShell 5 btw. The results are coming to me as "csv" after executing the stored proc. Any idea how I can iterate over the specific column and change the format of the values in just that column?I added the code I'm running to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I did not find out exactly what I wanted, we used a work around where we converted the Date fields in SQL Server to strings and that seemed to work for us.